# SSRS - Expression with Lookup in child group causes repeating label values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created a matrix with two column groups (year and quarter).

[image: groups]

The expression for the quarter label (the expression under [year]) is:

```
"Q " & CStr(Fields!quarter.Value)
```

So in the report I get Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 as quarter labels.

We have a international team so I need the others labels to be in german or in english, depending on the user. So I created a dataset with all translations which is filled from a translation table in the database. To get the correct translation for the label I use the **LOOKUP() function**.

When I use LOOKUP() to get the correct translation for the "amount Rest" textbox (located in the **year group**) it works fine:

[image: lookup-amountrest]

```
=LOOKUP(11, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!description.Value, "ds_Labels")
```

The result:

[image: result1]

But when I try to use LOOKUP() to get the translation for the "amount" textbox, which is located in the **quarter group**, the correct translation appears but the year label also starts with 2014 instead of 2008 and the quarter and year labels repeat:

[image: repeat]

```
=LOOKUP(17, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!description.Value, "ds_Labels")
```

The result:

[image: repeat2]

I've no idea what kind of bug this is and how I can get rid of it. Maybe someone can help me :)

---

**UPDATE**

Like I mentioned in the comments, the LOOKUP() function works in the first three columns of the quarter group. The report goes crazy if I try to use LOOKUP() in the fourth textbox of the quarter group (see the second last screenshot). But I still don't understand why...

---

**UPDATE 2**

When I deploy the report on a SSRS 2008R2 the report works completely fine. But I need it to run on SSRS 2012. Maybe it is a SSRS2012 bug?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that only one record is being returned when you look up the record(s) associated with id 17?  The function is designed to be used for 1 -to- 1 relationships

Comment: Yes. Every id is unique. So only one record is being returned

Comment: The translation table has 3 columns: ID (1, 2, 3, ...), language (de-DE or en-US) and description (translation). So the id 17 exists twice but together with the language it is unique. I tested the other LOOKUP() functions in the child group and they worked. The error appears when I try to lookup id 17. I don't get why this is the only id that doesn't work.

Comment: New test: even if I try to lookup id 21 in this textbox, the report goes crazy. So the problem is not the id, it is the fourth textbox in the quarter group. But why?!

Comment: Have you tried viewing the report code to make sure there isn't some wonky xml tag in that area?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug. Running `Lookup()` / `LookupSet()` queries against the same dataset that is being currently rendered in a tablix causes duplicates.

The only workaround I found is to pass a copy of the dataset and run `Lookup()` queries against that copy. This way everything works fine.